# Special OutputStream to work into memory and file depending on the amount of input data

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

Currently I'm working with an SSH client api providing me stdout and stderr as InputStreams. I have to read all the data from these streams at client side and provide an api for implementors to be able to work with these data the way they want (just drop it, write it to DB, process it etc). First I tried to keep the whole data read in byte arrays, but with huge amount of data (could happen sometimes) this can cause serious memory problems. But I don't want to write all the data of every call into files if that isn't really necessary.
Anyone knows about a solution which reads data into memory until it reaches a limit (like 1mb), after it writes data from memory to a file and appends all the remaining data of the inputstream to the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commons io has a workable solution: [DeferredFileOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you avoid reading the stream until you know what you are going to do with it?

If you use this approach you can dump them, read portions of data and write them to a database as you read it, or read and process the data as you read it.

This way you would not need to read more than 1 MB (or less) at any one time.

Comment: My job is providing the data in some way and let the integrators of the api to decide how to deal with the data. This is why I need to find a way to store the data effectively until it gets processed.

Comment: I don't understand how one follows the other. What is preventing you from only start retrieving the data when the caller of the API lets you know how it is going to be used?

Comment: The major point to do this way is that when an ssh call ends it closes the connection to the server, so I should read it's output before the connection is closed. But I don't know the data when will be processed by the implementor's code (the whole operation can be called asynchronously), and that's why I should store everything somehow. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I would keep the ssh connection open until the data it provides is needed.

Comment: This would still provide a buffer at both ends which you can increase so small results would effectively be in memory, but longer results would be waiting on the sender.